# How to make a submit button in WPF?

Tags: wpf, submit, keypress

When you press <kbd>Enter</kbd> anywhere in a HTML `form` it triggers its `action`, that is equivalent of pressing the `submit` button.
How to make a window that when I press  <kbd>Enter</kbd> anywhere it will trigger an event?

Comment: Is there a key preview property in WPF ? If so, setting it to true will send all key press directly to the form and you could use the keypress event to do it.

Answer (score 152, accepted):

Set the [`IsDefault`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.button.isdefault.aspx) property *on the button* to true to enable the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key to activate that button's action. There is also the [`IsCancel`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.button.iscancel.aspx) property that does the same thing for the <kbd>Escape</kbd> key.

Comment: That was my first suggestion in my answer below but then i noticed XMLforDummies didn't say he/she had an "OK" or "Submit" button on the form so i edited my answer. The only "problem" you may run into with this solution is, if a button other than the "OK"/"Submit" button has focus, pressing the enter key will only click the focused button and will not trigger the other event which is probably what you expect but just wanted to bring that point up.

Comment: I think that behavior is intentional. For example, if that button opened a modal dialog, and by hitting the enter key it trigger the submit, you wouldn't want both events to fire.

Answer (score 9):

Assign the `PreviewKeyDown` event to the window in XAML then check the `KeyEventArgs` in codebehind to determine if the user pressed the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

XAML code:

```
<Window
    [...]
    PreviewKeyDown="Window_PreviewKeyDown">
```

Code behind:

```
private void Window_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
    {
        // Whatever code you want if enter key is pressed goes here
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I just realized you didn't say you have a button on the form. You must have a button on the form before this will work.

Comment: If not, just add IsHitTestVisible="true" to the Window properties

Comment: Warning: This event will trigger on any control in the Window, even other buttons. Which is not normally an issue unless your users Tab around the form and use Enter to click buttons.

Comment: @WalterStabosz when you tab around, you should use anyway the space button to activate the highlighted button :)

Answer (score 0):

I found that the `DatePicker` control will swallow the <kbd>Enter</kbd> keypress so the default button doesn't get clicked. I wrote this event handler to fix that. Use the `PreviewKeyUp` to ensure that the `DatePicker` performs its date formatting code before clicking the default button.

```
private void DatePicker_PreviewKeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
    // event handler to click the default button when you hit enter on DatePicker
    if (e.Key == Key.Enter) {
        // https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/739358/WPF-Programmatically-click-the-default-button
        System.Windows.Input.AccessKeyManager.ProcessKey(null, "\x000D", false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<Button Name="btnDefault" IsDefault="true" Click="OnClickDefault">OK</Button>
```

You can do this by setting the button IsDefault property to True.

You can get detailed information from Microsoft's documents.

[Button.IsDefault Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.button.isdefault?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.6#examples)

Answer (score 0):

According to this https://wpf.2000things.com/tag/isdefault/

IsDefaulted will be true if all of the following is true:

1. IsDefault for the Button is set to true
2. Some other control currently has focus
3. **The control that currently has focus does not itself handle the ENTER key**

In my case I was trying to hit `Enter` from `TextBox` which already handles Enter Key. Turnaround was to set `AcceptsReturn = false` for `TextBox`. This option works if you do not need multiline textbox and Enter Key should submit entered text.
Also Text Binding should be updated while typing

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Text, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
 AcceptsReturn="False"/>
```